# At least two semesters when this professor had identical teaching programs?

Tags: combinatorics

A college professor has been working for the same department for $30$ years.  He taught two courses in each semester.  The department offers $15$ different courses.  Is it sure that there were at least two semesters when this professor had identical teaching programs?

(A year has two semesters.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

$$\binom{15}{2}=\frac{15!}{2!13!}=\frac{14\cdot 15}{2}\ldots$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  how many semesters has he taught?  Assuming he always teaches two different courses, how many unordered pairs of things can be chosen from $15$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $60$ pigeons rattle around in $105$ pigeonholes.

Answer (score 1):

There are ${15\choose 2}=105$ ways to choose two courses out of 15 coures, and there are 60 semesters in 30 years, so that's not true.